# MediaWiki Availibility for Local and External

Tags: ip, localhost, mediawiki

I'm currently hosting a MediaWiki site on my computer.  I'm forwarding port 80 to my computer, and I'm able to access it from outside the network, as long as the $wgServer variable in LocalSettings.php is set to my external ip address.  Although this works, I'm unable to view the wiki from within my local network, as any requests to [internal ip]/wikiname of my computer are redirected to the external ip's domain at [external ip]/wikiname and it won't load.  I can reverse this by setting $wgServer to instead be my internal ip, but then I am unable to access the site from outside my network.  Is there any way I can have it be accessible from both inside and outside of my home network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you don't set it at all? According to the documentation, if it's not set, it should be autodetected and *should* then work with both your internal IP and your external domain/ip.

See [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer#Autodetection) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @bhavicp is correct. Also the following worked for me if you want to specify both servers:

```
$wgServer         = "http://example.com";  // your external ip or domain
$wgInternalServer = "http://192.168.0.70"; // your local ip address
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `$wgServer` for external and `$wgInternalServer` for local. e.g.:

```
$wgServer = "http://www.my.com";
$wgInternalServer = "http://192.168.6.10:8080";
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgInternalServer

Answer (score -1):

I managed to make this work.
Add your external IP address to variable $wgExternalServer = 'your external IP address';, and to variable $wgInternalServer = 'your internal IP address';

It made my MediaWiki work, hopefully will yours also.

Comment: There is no settings called '$wgExternalServer', but there is '$wgInternalServer'. Thanks for your answer anyway, it led me to the correct answer which I have posted on this page.